# Iterative Algorithms Using Apply family: Metropolis-Hasting Alg

Tags: r, algorithm, for-loop, lapply

In algorithm building we often need both the previous and current iteration values. I am trying to leverage the apply family to improve the speed of the algorithm. I have built the Metropolis-Hasting Algorithm using a for loop but need help using the apply family (I prefer to use lapply). I have attached the code I have built thus far.

```
#For Loop Application of Metropolis-Hastings
phi <- matrix(,m+1,1) # (m+1) x 1 vector to save samples of x in
phi[1,] <- 0.5 # Starting value

set.seed(1603)
for(k in 1:m){
 phi.star <- runif(1) # Uniform proposal distribution
 phi.k <- phi[k,1]
 R <- min(1,(dbinom(1,1,phi.star)*dbeta(phi.star,1,1))/(dbinom(1,1,phi.k)*dbeta(phi.k,1,1)))
 phi[k+1,] <- dplyr::case_when(R > runif(1) ~ phi.star,
                            TRUE ~ phi.k) #Retain phi.star with probability R
}

#Lapply Function for Metropolis-Hastings
phi <- list()
set.seed(1603)
phi <- lapply(X = 1:m, function(k){
  phi.star <- runif(1) # Uniform proposal distribution
  phi.k <- phi[[k]]
  R <- min(1,(dbinom(1,1,phi.star)*dbeta(phi.star,1,1))/(dbinom(1,1,phi.k)*dbeta(phi.k,1,1)))
  phi.keep <- dplyr::case_when(R > runif(1) ~ phi.star,
                           TRUE ~ phi.k) #Retain phi.star with probability R
})

phi <- phi %>% do.call("rbind",.)
```

The issue arises because I am try to access the previous list value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're relying on the previous value, `apply()` isn't the way to go; [you really need to loop](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-not). If you want to speed up loops, a good way to go is to move to compiled code, which can be done quite easily via [`Rcpp`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rcpp). From Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html): "Typical bottlenecks that C++ can address include: Loops that can’t be easily vectorised because subsequent iterations depend on previous ones...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer version of my comment, with an example of how to implement it, and a comparison of the performance increase.

Since you're relying on the previous value, `apply()` isn't the way to go; [you really need to loop](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-not). If you want to speed up loops, a good way to go is to move to compiled code, which can be done quite easily via [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp). From Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html): "Typical bottlenecks that C++ can address include: Loops that can’t be easily vectorised because subsequent iterations depend on previous ones...."

Before showing how to implement in C++ via `Rcpp`, I'll note first that your M-H ratio here simplifies to `phi.star/phi.k` since `dbinom(1, 1, x)` = `x` for any `x` and `dbeta(x, 1, 1)` = 1 for any `x`.

Here's one way to implement your M-H sampler in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector mh_cpp(double starting_value, int n) {
    NumericVector phi(n+1);
    phi[0] = starting_value;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        double phi_star = R::runif(0.0, 1.0);
        double phi_k = phi[i];
        double r = phi_star / phi_k;
        if ( r >= 1 || R::runif(0.0, 1.0) < r ) {
            phi[i+1] = phi_star;
        }
        else {
            phi[i+1] = phi_k;
        }
    }
    return phi;
}
```

Then I created an R function for your sampler (notice how similar the code is!), and compared the performance:

```
mh_r <- function(starting_value, n) {
    phi <- numeric(n+1)
    phi[1] <- starting_value
    for ( k in 1:n ) {
        phi_star <- runif(1) # Uniform proposal distribution
        phi_k <- phi[k]
        r <- phi_star / phi_k
        phi[k+1] <- "if"(r >= 1 | runif(1) < r, phi_star, phi_k)
    }
    return(phi)
}

m <- 100000
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mh_r(0.5, m), mh_cpp(0.5, m))

Unit: milliseconds
           expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq        max
   mh_r(0.5, m) 2355.68150 2376.59047 2421.6640 2383.96823 2408.27571 3816.37139
 mh_cpp(0.5, m)   10.54044   10.59464   10.8235   10.61732   10.65326   25.43983

m <- 1000
microbenchmark(mh_r(0.5, m), mh_cpp(0.5, m))
Unit: microseconds
           expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max
   mh_r(0.5, m) 22199.272 22395.6200 24223.8546 22511.8160 22705.792 39525.690
 mh_cpp(0.5, m)   115.186   118.4795   130.4884   131.0385   135.016   403.093
```

So, by moving to C++ via `Rcpp`, we've gotten this to be about 200x faster at both 1000 iterations and 100000 iterations.

For some introductory information on using `Rcpp`, I'd suggest the [Rcpp Introduction Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) and Hadley's chapter on it in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clear, concise, and thorough answer to the question. Appreciate the insight and definitely looking into Rcpp. Thank you again @duckmayr for the suggestions.